# Card overflow from column

Tags: css, angular, col

I have a card that contains a form. Instead of having the form go down the page, I decided to insert a y-scroll bar, so I could determine how much of the form is seen by the user at a time. The problem is, it looks like the columns are overflowing out of the card.

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1%;
  width: 115%;
  margin-left: -9%;
  max-height: 42%;    
}
    
.column {
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: -15%;
  margin-right: 175%;
  margin-top: -5%;
}
    
.column2 {
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: -200%;
  margin-right: -1%;
  margin-top: -8%;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid #E1E0E5    
}
    
/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
    
.scroll-box {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 40%;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column2">
      <div class="scroll-box">
        <form #f="ngForm" novalidate>
          <!-- steps of the form -->
          <button type="submit" (click)="save(f.value, f.valid)">Submit</button>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I keep the column height as the card it is in, and not have overflow out of the card?

What I am currently seeing:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the column heights right, try using flexbox:

```
.card {
  display: flex;
}
```

To prevent overflow use the `overflow` or the `overflow-y` properties for example:

```
.column2 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Or maybe (depending on what your doing):

```
.card {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```